# how can I set Gui like this photo

Tags: java

```java
package matchgame;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
public class Start_Manu extends JFrame {
    Start_Manu()
    {
        JLabel welcome=new JLabel("Welcome to Match Card Game ☺");
        JButton start=new JButton("Start");
        JPanel manustart=new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        manustart.add(welcome,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        manustart.add(start,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(manustart);
        //set Frame
        setSize(800, 600);
        setTitle("Match Card Game");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Start_Manu a=new Start_Manu();
    }

}
```

I want to set likes this photo.
[image]

When click start button go to the game state

But when I write the code.

[image]

Can you advise me how to write the code likes my first photo?

Comment: so you want a small centered button, instead of a 100% sized one, right?

Comment: Yes and  I want to add the size of text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a rough design. You want to nest different layout methods. This should be an accurate framework for your design, you can tweak some numbers (like spaces etc.) to your own liking.

```
        //Main Panel to contain everything
        JPanel main = new JPanel();
        main.setLayout(new BoxLayout(main,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        JLabel welcome=new JLabel("Welcome to Match Card Game ☺");
        //Setting prefered Font-Size
        welcome.setFont(new Font(welcome.getName(), Font.PLAIN, 24));


        JButton start=new JButton("Start Game");

        //Change button size and apparence
        start.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,50));
        start.setContentAreaFilled(false);


        //Add two sub-panels for advanced positioning
        JPanel welcome_p=new JPanel(new FlowLayout(1,0,150));
        JPanel button_p=new JPanel();

        //Set welcomepanel size to lower space to Button
        welcome_p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,150));
        welcome_p.add(welcome);

        button_p.add(start);
        main.add(welcome_p);

        main.add(button_p);

        add(main);
        setSize(800, 600);
        setTitle("Match Card Game");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you have a VDO tutorial about creating GUI? I don't understand about Dimension and Why did you set  ```FlowLayout(1,0,150)```  (How did you know? set gap x,y to 1 and 0) @Niklas

Comment: You can always use the official oracle docs for the FlowLayout. They also have an visual guide for all layouts: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand 1 thing why you set Alignment to 1 what is the meaning I think it only has ```FlowLayout.direction``` @Niklas

Comment: what is the meaning of this line ```welcome_p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,150)); ``` I change 150 to 0 but not thing change @Niklas